# JQuery Datepicker date is captured only when the day is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Ran into a weird problem with jQuery Datepicker. I've set the option **changeMonth: true** to enable month change.

Say, if my datepicker displays a date **02/05/2013** and when I just change the month to April(not clicking on any day in the control), the date gets displayed as **02/04/2013**. But when I get the date from the control, I end up getting the old month value instead of the newly selected one.

code:

```
$('#uxStartDateTime').datetimepicker({
    timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    showButtonPanel: false,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});

//getting the date
var startDate = $('#uxStartDateTime').datetimepicker('getDate');

//formatting this date to it send via ajax to c#
startDate = startDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (startDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + startDate.getDate() + " " + startDate.getHours() + ":" + startDate.getMinutes();
```

Is there anything wrong with my method or is this a known issue?

Comment: It's supposed to be that way, you can scroll back and forth between months, but you have to actually select a date to change the date, it's the way just about every datepicker works!

Comment: @adeneo oh I see. Is there any hack to overcome this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the expected datepicker behavior, as adeneo pointed out in his comment.  If you want to change this, you will have to write a method that is fired on change of month.

```
$('.ui-datepicker-month').change(function () {
    // if there is a value in your controller, change it
});
```

I'll leave the actual logic of adding/subtracting months to a date to you.

Comment: thanks, I got confused as the text field showed updated value when I changed month.